# csv to multi table insert update

Tags: python, mysql, csv

Finally created account because this  one was not:
I created a csv like this:

```
name, age, course

tables:
users[id, name, age]
user_course[user_id, course_id]
course[id,name]
```

Now i have to import this csv along with runtime foreign key created.
Any way to achieve this with 100K records

```
example :
sample.csv
jhon,28,botony
samuel,39,physics

database table

table USERS
columns: id<pk>, name, age

table COURSES
columns: id<pk>, name

table USER_COURSE
columns: id<pk>, user_id<F_key_users>, course_id<F_key_courses>
```

I have to insert my csv in these tables.

Thanks if anyone help me out, I can not alter db.

Comment: Could you give us a little more? I have a hard time to understand your problem. Maybe an example would help.

Answer (score 0):

For USERS:
The primary key is generated by the DB (or should be)

Users:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'users.csv'
INTO TABLE users
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(NAME, AGE);
```

Course:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'course.csv'
INTO TABLE courses
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(NAME);
```

Same syntax for the last table, just change the table and column name

For the columns you want to skip, use `@dummy`

So to follow this order

```
jhon,28,botany

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'users.csv'
INTO TABLE users
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(NAME, AGE, @dummy);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'course.csv'
INTO TABLE courses
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@dummy, @dummy, NAME);
```

You can't really control the PK in the DB but you know that it will always increment by 1. So based on that, you can create the third table.

If you can, I'd suggest separating the courses in a difference csv so you create each course only once and then in the third table reference the course to the student.

Comment: problem arises when my user table has already existing records[based on name] in USER table, some courses, users are already, in that case I have to update respective foreign keys in table USER_COURSE.

Comment: When you load a file, it should not affect existing records, it simply adds to the tables. For the third table, it's difficult to manage if you don't know the PK

Comment: yup ,same problem i m facing,

Comment: I am summarizing what i have understand.
1: insert only new users
2: insert only new course
3:fetch foreign keys of users, courses both existing and inserted
4:insert in third table

any optimization possible

Comment: Yeah, exactly. So you want to add the Users and Courses individually because they can co-exist without each other. You can have a user without any courses, and a course without any users. The third table would be joining them together. This would make it easier to reuse the same user and course multiple times without having to recreate a new instance.

Comment: I am not sure if my answer has helped you solve your problem @joefor

Comment: sorry ,but then problem arises because, these all queries in 100k record hangs

Comment: I am not sure how to approach it if you already have existing data :/. Specially for the third table :( Hopefully someone else might help you better